# javadoc location in for Java ME?

Tags: eclipse, java-me, javadoc

Using Eclipse 3.5 and the plugin for mtj.

Where can I find the Javadoc location for Java ME?

How can I set the Javadoc location in Eclipse? I am using motodev sdk and also installed a mtj as Eclipse plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MIDP 2.0 JSR-118 JavaDoc](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html).
[All JavaME docs.](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javame/)

Comment: thankx,
 but can u pls tell me how i can set javadoc location in eclipse as i am using motodev sdk and also installed a mtj as eclipse plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the javadoc locations for the libraries provided by the SDK on MTJ. In order to do that open the Preferences->Java ME->Device Management then select the device that you want to edit and select Edit button. Choose the Libraries tab to edit javadoc locations.